# Moving value to next row based on groupby Item

Tags: r

I am a newbie to R. Can someone help me with this

For below df, I need to check only the first row of each Item and make it's price as 0 in Column "New Price" and add it's price to the next row for same Item.

Df

```
df <- structure(list(Item = c("A", "A", "B", "B"), city = c("Delhi", 
"Mumbai", "Delhi", "Mumbai"), price = c(10L, 5L, 10L, 5L), value = c(0L, 
2L, 1L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))


Item    city   price  value
 A      Delhi   10      0
 A      Mumbai   5      2
 B      Delhi   10      1
 B      Mumbai   5      2
```

Here for Item A, we will check the first row and in the Newprice column we will make it's value 0 and move 10 to the next row for same item to make it 15. Similarly for Item B

I want the below output

Output

```
Item    city   price  value   Newprice
 A      Delhi   10      0        0
 A      Mumbai   5      2        15
 B      Delhi   15      0        0
 B      Mumbai   5      4        20
```

Comment: `Price` values for `Item` `B` for `Delhi` is different in input and output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have only two rows for each group we could `group_by` `Item` and add 0 and `sum` of `Price` in new column. Using `dplyr` that would be

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Item) %>%
  mutate(Newprice = c(0, sum(price, na.rm = TRUE)))

#  Item  city   price value Newprice
# <chr> <chr>  <int> <int>    <dbl>
#1 A     Delhi     10     0        0
#2 A     Mumbai     5     2       15
#3 B     Delhi     10     1        0
#4 B     Mumbai     5     2       15
```

The equivalent base R and `data.table` alternatives would be

```
df$NewPrice <- with(df, ave(price, Item,FUN =function(x)c(0, sum(x, na.rm = TRUE))))

library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, NewPrice := c(0, sum(price, na.rm = TRUE)), by = Item]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option that would take care of edge cases as well

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(Item) %>% 
    mutate(Newprice = (row_number() == n())*sum(price))
# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Groups:   Item [2]
#  Item  city   price value Newprice
#  <chr> <chr>  <int> <int>    <int>
#1 A     Delhi     10     0        0
#2 A     Mumbai     5     2       15
#3 B     Delhi     10     1        0
#4 B     Mumbai     5     2       15
```

i.e. if the number of elements in groups is not equal to 2 also this would work